# Вычислить функцию

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

только начал учить C#, подскажите пожалуйста код

```
double x,y
double f = (Math.PI / 2) - (Math.Sqrt(2 * x) - 
              (x + Math.Pow(y, 2) / (0.75 * Math.tan) * Math.Abs(x + y))
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас какой-то висячий тангенс образовался

```
double f = Math.PI/2 - Math.Sqrt(2*x) - (x+y*y)/(0.75 * Math.Tan(Math.Abs(x+y)))
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как его сделать не висячим? Слегка не понимаю, пишет, что math не содержит определения для tan

Comment: @Geniune Tan потому что, это ж несложно https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.tan

Comment: Висячим в вашем коде я назвал, потому что это функция, требует аргументов в скобках, а у вас выражение обрывается закрывающей скобкой

Comment: @Geniune Помогло?